# Code coverage don't generate report on azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**my objective:**

is to successfully publish my coverage report in a pipeline on azure devops.
To send it to SonarCloud

**my successes**

locally on my pc
I manage to generate the coverage report in **html** format and also in **xml**

**1. script task on my pipeline:**

```
      - script: |
          npx ng test --code-coverage --karma-config src/karma-ci.conf.js
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        displayName: Generate unit tests report
```

**2. kama-ci.config.js file:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'TestResults/junit',
      outputFile: 'unittest-results.xml',
      useBrowserName: false
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'cobertura',
      dir : 'TestResults',
      subdir: 'coverage',
      file: 'code-coverage.xml'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'junit', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
        ]
      }
    },
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

**3. Result error:**

But the problem is, report generation always starts and fails in the pipeline.
Here is his result, despite the fact that I give it the condition of always succeeding.

```
2021-06-02T14:50:42.8314347Z ##[section]Starting: Generate unit tests
2021-06-02T14:50:42.8319061Z ==============================================================================
2021-06-02T14:50:42.8319314Z Task         : Command line
2021-06-02T14:50:42.8319582Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2021-06-02T14:50:42.8319857Z Version      : 2.182.0
2021-06-02T14:50:42.8320038Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-06-02T14:50:42.8320318Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2021-06-02T14:50:42.8320658Z ==============================================================================
2021-06-02T14:50:42.9528480Z Generating script.
2021-06-02T14:50:42.9529859Z Script contents:
2021-06-02T14:50:42.9530447Z npx ng test --code-coverage --karma-config src/karma-ci.conf.js
2021-06-02T14:50:42.9530922Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2021-06-02T14:50:42.9558445Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/7177135e-e9ad-4ecf-b6f1-86193e021ca3.sh
2021-06-02T14:51:01.5747869Z [32m02 06 2021 14:51:01.570:INFO [karma-server]: [39mKarma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
2021-06-02T14:51:01.5749272Z [32m02 06 2021 14:51:01.573:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
2021-06-02T14:51:01.5774208Z [32m02 06 2021 14:51:01.577:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Chrome
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4612458Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4614556Z ERROR in [96mapp/services/dealflow-secondary.service.ts[0m:[93m4[0m:[93m37[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module '../entities/ISecondaryPortfolio'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4615270Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4616058Z [7m4[0m import { ISecondaryPortfolio } from '../entities/ISecondaryPortfolio';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4616981Z [7m [0m [91m                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4618161Z [96mapp/shared/api/geography.api.ts[0m:[93m8[0m:[93m27[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module 'src/app/ui/funds/fund-list/models/Geography'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4618794Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4619553Z [7m8[0m import { Geography } from 'src/app/ui/funds/fund-list/models/Geography';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4620454Z [7m [0m [91m                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4621635Z [96mapp/shared/services/geography.service.ts[0m:[93m2[0m:[93m27[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module 'src/app/ui/funds/fund-list/models/Geography'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4622232Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4622986Z [7m2[0m import { Geography } from 'src/app/ui/funds/fund-list/models/Geography';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4623886Z [7m [0m [91m                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4625110Z [96mapp/ui/dealflow/add-fund-portfolio/add-fund-portfolio.component.ts[0m:[93m7[0m:[93m37[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module 'src/app/entities/ISecondaryPortfolio'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4625760Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4626506Z [7m7[0m import { ISecondaryPortfolio } from 'src/app/entities/ISecondaryPortfolio';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4627440Z [7m [0m [91m                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4628643Z [96mapp/ui/dealflow/dealflow.service.ts[0m:[93m13[0m:[93m37[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module '../../entities/ISecondaryPortfolio'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4629250Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4629996Z [7m13[0m import { ISecondaryPortfolio } from '../../entities/ISecondaryPortfolio';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4630925Z [7m  [0m [91m                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4632053Z [96mapp/ui/dealflow/models/DealFlow.ts[0m:[93m1[0m:[93m37[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module 'src/app/entities/ISecondaryPortfolio'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4632630Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4633391Z [7m1[0m import { ISecondaryPortfolio } from "src/app/entities/ISecondaryPortfolio";
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4634782Z [7m [0m [91m                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4636019Z [96mapp/ui/dealflow/project-secondary/project-secondary.component.ts[0m:[93m15[0m:[93m37[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module '../../../entities/ISecondaryPortfolio'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4638214Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4640037Z [7m15[0m import { ISecondaryPortfolio } from '../../../entities/ISecondaryPortfolio';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4641024Z [7m  [0m [91m                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4642193Z [96mapp/ui/dealflow/send-to-mdm-popup/send-to-mdm-popup.component.ts[0m:[93m5[0m:[93m30[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module 'src/app/entities/IMDMResponse'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4642778Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4643427Z [7m5[0m import { IMDMResponse } from 'src/app/entities/IMDMResponse';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4644246Z [7m [0m [91m                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4645318Z [96mapp/ui/dealflow/tests-dealflow/dealflow.spec.ts[0m:[93m1[0m:[93m37[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module '../../../entities/ISecondaryPortfolio'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4645885Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4646561Z [7m1[0m import { ISecondaryPortfolio } from '../../../entities/ISecondaryPortfolio';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4647398Z [7m [0m [91m                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4648510Z [96mapp/ui/funds/fund-list/create-fund/create-fund.component.spec.ts[0m:[93m2[0m:[93m27[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module '../models/Geography'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4649050Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4649676Z [7m2[0m import { Geography } from '../models/Geography';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4650403Z [7m [0m [91m                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4651471Z [96mapp/ui/funds/fund-list/create-fund/create-fund.component.ts[0m:[93m15[0m:[93m27[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2307: [0mCannot find module '../models/Geography'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4652001Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4652603Z [7m15[0m import { Geography } from '../models/Geography';
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4653352Z [7m  [0m [91m                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2021-06-02T14:51:03.4653685Z 
2021-06-02T14:51:03.5172693Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2021-06-02T14:51:03.5208748Z ##[section]Finishing: Generate unit tests
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install` command before running the test?

Comment: yes, i restore my package with task Npm@1, and the command install

Comment: The error shows it tried to import some modules from the specified path. And the modules cannot be found in the path. Eg. `import { ISecondaryPortfolio } from 'src/app/entities/ISecondaryPortfolio'`. Could you run `ls -lR` in the pipeline to check if these folders exist when the pipeline run?

Answer (score 3):

You should add "reporters" inside "coverageReporter" in your karma.config, like so:

```
coverageReporter: {
  type : 'cobertura',
  dir : 'TestResults',
  subdir: 'coverage',
  file: 'code-coverage.xml',
  reporters: [ { type: 'cobertura' } ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. My project is:**

Front end project with Node.Js and npm package

```
 Angular CLI: 8.3.23 
 Node: 12.18.3  
 OS: win32 x64
 Angular: 8.2.14
```

**1. i show you my pipeline**

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
      - v*
variables:
  - name: ARTIFACTS_FEED_NAME
    value: MyFeed
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: 10.15.x
            displayName: Install and use 10.x Node.js version
          - task: Npm@1
            inputs:
              command: install
              customRegistry: useFeed
              customFeed: $(ARTIFACTS_FEED_NAME)
            displayName: Packages restore

          - script: |
              ls 
            displayName: Check source output
            
          - script: |
              npx ng test --code-coverage --karma-config src/karma-ci.conf.js
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            displayName: Generate unit tests report

          - script: |
              ls src
            displayName: Check unit tests output

          - task: PublishTestResults@2
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
              testResultsFiles: '**/TestResults/junit/unittest-results.xml'
            displayName: Publish unit test results

          - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
            displayName: Publish code coverage report
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
              # summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverage/**/TestResults/code-coverage.xml'
              summaryFileLocation: '**/src/TestResults/coverage/code-coverage.xml'
              failIfCoverageEmpty: true
```